# There are gray stains on the image after converting to another format after use ImageMagick php

Tags: php, imagemagick

I have the following problem. I use ImageMagick for the reformat PDF to JPG.  Everything goes well but on the picture appear the mark in the form of triangles. Here is an example code and images before and after.

```
$pdf_file = $name[0] . '.pdf';

$im = new imagick($pdf_file);

$i = 0;

foreach ($im as $_img) {

    $i++;

    $_img->setResolution(300, 300);

    $im->setImageColorspace(255);

    $im->setCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);

    $im->setCompressionQuality(60);

    $_img->setImageFormat('jpg');

    $_img->writeImage(__DIR__ .'/'.$main_name[0] . '.jpg');

}


$im->destroy();

$new_name = DIR .'/'. $main_name[0] . '.jpg';

$new_name1 = $main_name[0] . '.jpg';

//$new_name1 = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $new_name1);


$size = getimagesize($new_name1);
$ratio = $size[0]/$size[1]; // width/height
if( $ratio > 1) {
    $width = 700;
    $height = 700/$ratio;
}
else {
    $width = 700*$ratio;
    $height = 700;
}
$src = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($new_name1));
$dst = imagecreatetruecolor($width,$height);
imagecopyresampled($dst,$src,0,0,0,0,$width,$height,$size[0],$size[1]);
imagedestroy($src);
imagepng($dst,$new_name1); // adjust format as needed
imagedestroy($dst);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The "stains" are JPEG artifacts.  Use a higher "quality" (60 is pretty low; 90 would be better for this type of image), or use PNG instead.  The higher-quality JPEG will of course occupy a larger filesize, but that's the tradeoff.

Comment: Please try converting to PNG or to PPM instead of JPEG. If the stains are still there then we'll know whether to blame the JPG encoding or the PDF decoding.